# Calculating ICMP packet checksum

Tags: c++, networking, icmp

I am writing a simple program to send and recieve icmp messages.
I have written the following to calculate the checksum for the icmp message:

```
char sbuf[] = "        This is a test message..";
sbuf[0] = 0x10;
sbuf[1] = 0x00;
sbuf[2] = 0x00;
sbuf[3] = 0x00;
sbuf[4] = 0x00;
sbuf[5] = 0x00;
sbuf[6] = 0x00;
sbuf[7] = 0x00;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(sbuf); i += 2)
    checksum += (sbuf[i] << 8) + sbuf[i + 1];

if (sizeof(sbuf) % 2)
    checksum += sbuf[sizeof(sbuf) - 1] << 8;
checksum = (checksum >> 16) + (checksum & 0xffff);
checksum = ~(checksum + (checksum >> 16));
sbuf[2] = checksum >> 8;
sbuf[3] = checksum & 0x00ff;
```

The problem is, the calculated checksum is not correct when the messege length is an odd number.
There is something wrong with the `checksum += sbuf[sizeof(sbuf) - 1] << 8;` part but i can't figure out what

How do i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [RFC 1071](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071)?

Comment: @barmar Well i have now. So from what i understood, i dont have to shift the remaining byte. So i changed it to `checksum += sbuf[sizeof(sbuf) - 1]` but it's still not working.. I feel like i'm doing something terribly wrong...

Comment: You *do* need to shift the extra byte, the result should be the same as if the string was extended with one more 0 byte. Silly question: is `checksum` declared to be an unsigned type with at least 32 bits, e.g., `uint_least32_t`?

Comment: @Casey, Yes it's declared as `unsigned int`. I'm sure aleast it's 32 bits in my complier (Visual studio 2013). After a few tracing without any luck, I have to ask.. If the message ends with a `00` byte, why does it make a difference to add the left over byte to the checksum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think i have found the soloution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(sbuf) - 1; i += 2)
    checksum += (sbuf[i] << 8) + sbuf[i + 1];

if (sizeof(sbuf) % 2)
    checksum += sbuf[sizeof(sbuf) - 1];
```

Now this does calculate the correct checksum for any lenght of messege. But i can't confirm if it is a real solution or it just works because the last byte of my message is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

You may like my version

```
uint16_t Checksum(const void* data, size_t len) {
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(data);
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    if (len & 1) {
        // len is odd
        sum = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(p)[len - 1];
    }
    len /= 2;
    while (len--) {
        sum += *p++;
        if (sum & 0xffff0000) {
            sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
        }
    }
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(~sum);
}

std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(4)
          << Checksum(sbuf, sizeof(sbuf))
          << std::endl;
```